# Can anyone help me in converting a english sentence into logical expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

The propositions are given as below. 
P: Grizzly bears have been seen in the area.
Q:Hiking is safe on the trail.
R:Berries are ripe along the trail.

Now tell me, what will be the logical expression of this, and why:

"If berries are ripe along the trail, hiking is safe if and 
only if grizzly bears have not been seen in the area."

The problem is from the book "discrete mathematics and its application" by Keeneth H.Rosen page no.17 in its sixth edition.

Now I had tried to do myself. And I finished with $((R\rightarrow Q)\leftrightarrow(\neg P))$.
But in my book the ans was  $(R\rightarrow(Q\leftrightarrow(\neg P)))$, but I can't understand why this is the answer. I think the answer should be $((R\rightarrow Q)\leftrightarrow(\neg P))$
because $\rightarrow$ has precedence over $\leftrightarrow$.

Could anyone please tell me what is the right answer is and why.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that"$\to$ has precedence over "$\leftrightarrow$"?

Comment: One upside to using propositional formulae in the first place is that natural language is ambiguous. Indeed, there is no reason (in this case) the book's answer is the only correct one.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3327577/precedence-between-implication-and-bi-implication

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, people set orders of precedence in logical expressions, like "$\Rightarrow$ before $\Leftrightarrow$", but that's definitely not standard in every field. In the english language, *this rule is wrong*.

An if-clause of the shape "If $A$, then $B$" reads as $A \Rightarrow B$, even if $A$ and $B$ are more complicated expressions. The sentence "$A$ if and only if $B$" binds $A$ and $B$ together, and reads $(A \Leftrightarrow B)$ but it can't bind any statements outside the sentence. Thus "If $A$, then $B$ if and only if $C$" reads as $A \Rightarrow (B \Leftrightarrow C)$. The comma is another indicator of the intended order of precedence, since it separates $A$ from $B$ and $C$. As the comments mentioned, there are no absolute rules here, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: How would i represent (A->B) <-> C  in English. And what will be the difference between  (A->B) <-> C And A->(B <-> C) when representing in English.

Comment: The sentence "If and only if from $A$ follows $B$, then $C$" would do the job. But you could realize $C \Leftrightarrow (A \Rightarrow B)$ (which is equivalent) a bit more elegantly: "If and only if $C$, $B$ if $A$", like "If and only if there are no Grizzlys around, hiking on the trail is safe if there are berries ripe along it."